# External Users permissions

Tags: google-bigquery

I would like to grant read permissions on a dataset to a user. I don't mind paying for the storage, but i don't want to pay for the queries (Similar to the publicly available datasets).

1. What kind of permissions / share I need to grant this user?
2. How should that user act in order to view my data in the web UI?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give the users read access to the dataset. You can do this from the bigquery web ui by clicking on the dropdown by the dataset name in he left panel and selecting 'share dataset...'. Any queries that they run against the tables in the dataset will be billed to their project rather than yours.

If you use the web ui to share the dataset it will also trigger an e-mail to them which has a link that will add the dataset to their display. Alternately, they can click on the dropdown next to their project  name in the top left of the page, click on "Switch To Project" and then  "Display project". Then they can add the project name of the dataset you've shared with them. They will only see the datasets they explicitly have access to.